# oclif generate command won't pass initial tests

Tags: node.js, typescript, salesforce, command-line-interface, oclif

I generated a new CLI with `oclif`, and everything was functional with the "hello, world" example provided. However, when I went to edit the initial "hello world" example I am no longer able to get the unittests to pass.

I assumed I had removed something important, and I created another command `oclif generate command mycmd2` to compare the differences, but this also fails the generated unittests.

Building and executing the command directly from the bin folder (`.\bin\dev.cmd mycmd`) produces the correct values.

project structure:

```
my-app/
├─ packages/
│  ├─ cli/
│  │  ├─ src/
│  │  │  ├─ commands/
│  │  │  │  ├─ mycmd.ts
│  │  │  │  ├─ mycmd2.ts
│  │  │  ├─ index.ts
│  │  ├─ test/
│  │  │  ├─ commands/
│  │  │  │  ├─ mycmd.test.ts
│  │  │  │  ├─ mycmd2.test.ts
│  ├─ otherPackage/
```

Comment: Appears that this is something they are aware of: https://github.com/oclif/test/issues/390

Comment: I ended up fixing this by migrating to `yarn` workspaces instead of npm and then adding this snippet to the package.json of the oclif generated cli:


"installConfig": {
    "hoistingLimits": "workspaces"
  }